# Ionic 2: Uncaught ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined

Tags: typescript, npm, undefined, ionic2

I was trying to update my Ionic 2 installation on my mac and after, when I try to run my app in the browser, I'm getting (sometimes) a blank screen and the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined
```

This also happens with the blank project from their tutorials, straight from github.  So it's NOT just my project.

**Q) Can someone point out the correct steps to bring Ionic 2 and its dependencies up to date via terminal so I can work again?**

Thanks!

Some system info to help you help me:

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:AppHazard daveshirman$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002 




Davids-MacBook-Air:AppHazard daveshirman$ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
├── acs@1.2.0
├── alloy@1.8.5
├── angular2@2.0.0-beta.15
├── bower@1.7.9
├── cordova@6.1.1
├── es6-promise@3.1.2
├── es6-shim@0.35.0
├── install@0.6.1
├── ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
├── ionic-framework@2.0.0-beta.2
├── ios-deploy@1.8.6
├── ios-sim@5.0.8
├── npm@3.8.6
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
├── titanium@5.0.7
├── typedphonegap@0.0.3
├── typescript@1.8.10
├── typings@0.7.12
├── uninstall@0.0.0-reserved
└── zone.js@0.6.11
```